# Mahout: Creating vectors from Text, How can we support foreign language?

Tags: text, mahout

http://mahout.apache.org/users/basics/creating-vectors-from-text.html

Mahout teach out how to create vectors from text using lucene?

Is there a way to support character other than English?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Data mining support other languages other than English?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28187036/does-data-mining-support-other-languages-other-than-english)

Answer (score 0):

It requires a few steps to make a document become vector. Because you mentioned Apache Lucene and Mahout, I will briefly explain how you can obtain vectors by using Mahout and Lucene. It's a little bit tedious but you have to see the big picture in order to understand what you need to do to create vectors from languages other than English.

Firstly, by using Apache Lucene, you can create index files from text. In this step, the text is passed through Analyzer. The Analyzer will break the text into pieces (or technically *tokens*) and do most of important things including removing stopping words (*the, but, a, an, ...*), stemming words, converting to lower cases, etc. So, you can see, to support different languages, all you need to do is to build your own Analyzer.

In Lucene, **StandardAnalyzer** is the most well-equipped analyzer you can use, it supports non-English languages like Chinese, Japanese, Korean.

Secondly, after you obtain the index files, the next step is to mining text by using Mahout. No matter what you are going to do with your text, you have to convert the index files to **SequenceFile** since Mahout can only read inputs in SequenceFile format. The workaround is to use **SequenceFilesFromLuceneStorage** class in Mahout to do it.

Thirdly, after you have the sequence file, you now can convert it to vectors. For example, you can use the class **SparseVectorsFromSequenceFiles** to do it.

Hope it helps.